# Extraction of quadratic terms with state-space representation

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, quadratics, nonlinear-system

I am having trouble with transforming the dynamics of a 4DOF gyroscope to a neat state-space representation. The system has the following set of equations:
$T_i + f_i(\omega, \alpha) = 0;\;i:1-4$ .

The function $f_i(\omega, \alpha)$ can be written as two independent functions containing only $\omega$ or $\alpha$: $f_i(\omega, \alpha) = g_i(\omega) + h_i(\alpha)$. Here, $h_i(\alpha)$ is linear in $\alpha$, $g_i(\omega)$ is quadratic in $\omega$.

The given equation set can be transformed into a (descriptor) state-space representation:
$E\dot{x} = A(x) + Bu$, where $x = \omega$, $\dot{x} = \alpha$ and $u = T$. Note that the state and input vectors are all members of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Because $A(x)$ has the property of it being quadratic in $\omega$, one can define $g_i(\omega) = \omega^TA_i\omega$, where $A$ is an upper-triangular matrix.

$A(x)$ now becomes $\left[\matrix{\omega^TA_1\omega\\ \omega^TA_2\omega\\ \omega^TA_3\omega\\ \omega^TA_4\omega }\right]$ which leads to $\left[\matrix{\omega^TA_1\\ \omega^TA_2\\ \omega^TA_3\\ \omega^TA_4 }\right]\omega$. But I cannot remove extract $\omega^T$ without breaking the dimensions of the whole term.

How can I extract both $\omega$ terms to end with a conventional quadratic matrix equation?

Personally, I am thinking of adding an extra matrix $P$ in between $\omega^T$ and $A$, but I do not know for sure if this alters the system equations and also what the entries of this matrix should be.

Comment: Well, if you want to find matrix $Q$ such that $\omega^T Q \omega$ will give you a vector of quadratic forms it seems impossible to do: $\omega^T$ is $1 \times 4$ and $\omega$ is $4 \times 1$, so $Q$ can only be $4 \times 4$ in order to have correct matrix multiplication. The tensor product however might work (but I'm not sure).

Comment: Indeed, dimension-wise, that extraction will not work. I am not too familiar with tensors, so I would not know what would be the solution with tensors.